# How to plot using matplotlib and pandas in pyspark environment?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, matplotlib, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very large pyspark dataframe and I took a sample and convert it into pandas dataframe

```
sample = heavy_pivot.sample(False, fraction = 0.2, seed = None)
sample_pd = sample.toPandas()
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
sample_pd[['client_id', 'beer_freq']].head(10)


  client_id  beer_freq
0   1000839   0.000000
1   1002185   0.000000
2   1003366   1.000000
3   1005218   1.000000
4   1005483   1.000000
5    100964   0.434783
6    101272   0.166667
7   1017462   0.000000
8   1020561   0.000000
9   1023646   0.000000
```

I want to plot a histogram of column `"beer_freq"`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend('agg')

sample_pd.hist('beer_freq', bins = 100)
```

The plot did not show up...
It gives results like this:

```
 >>>array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f60f6fd0750>]], dtype=object)
```

It seems like that I cannot write general python code using matplotlib and pandas dataframe to plot figures in pyspark environment.

If I call `plt.show()` Nothing happens...

Comment: Did you call `plt.show()`?

Comment: @DavidG   Yes, if I add `plt.show()`  Nothing happens. It is so weird.

Answer (score 2):

%matplotlib inline is not supported in Databricks.
You can display matplotlib figures using display(). For an example, see https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/visualizations/matplotlib-and-ggplot.html

Comment: As of [DBR 6.4+](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/visualizations/matplotlib-and-ggplot.html), `%matplotlib inline` is supported, so you no longer need do call `display()`

Answer (score 1):

As of [DBR 6.4+](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/visualizations/matplotlib-and-ggplot.html), you can use `%matplotlib inline`.

```py
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
iris.hist('sepal_width', bins = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not accessible. as Gaurav mentioned, use `display()` as follow:

```
col_df = heavy_pivot.select('beer_freq')
display(col_df)
```

like that, you don't need to change it to pandas dataframe and the final plot looks the same. just after displaying, use the plot button under the output to choose histogram.

[image]

source:

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using ipython/ python shell in a terminal. Since you are using spark, I guess your shell environment is running on a remote server. In order to plot on a remote server, you need to enable X11 forwarding. See https://adoni.github.io/2019/01/08/plot-on-server/#through-x11 as a reference.

Other options:

1. Install jupyter notebook or jupyterlab, and plot in a notebook environment
2. Save the plot using `plt.savefig('plot.png')` to save the plot to a file. Then download to local.