# Apache Zeppelin - Pandas Scatter Matrix Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, apache-zeppelin

I tried to plot a scatter matrix in Zeppelin, with no luck so far. 
Other graph types works well.

```
%pyspark
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
#plt.show()
```

I got inspired by examples [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) and [here](https://github.com/beljun/zeppelin-plotly)

I only get the following output, but it doesn't display anything

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e4c6110>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e459050>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f5535b2ee10>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e315090>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e459690>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f5541ef4f10>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f5541e87490>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e27ae10>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e36f7d0>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e36f890>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e40b850>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e3e07d0>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e46fb10>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553e40b7d0>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553538b5d0>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7f553565ab10>]],
      dtype=object)
```

**EDIT**

When I uncomment `plt.show` nothing happens, and the paragraph keeps running forever.

When I check the logs I see :

```
INFO [2019-02-17 19:41:40,633] ({qtp684874119-552} NotebookServer.java[onClose]:371) - Closed connection to 10.0.0.218 : 36852. (1006) EOF: Broken pipe
ERROR [2019-02-17 19:41:40,633] ({qtp684874119-552} NotebookServer.java[onMessage]:365) - 
Can't handle message: {"op":"GET_NOTE","data":{"id":"2DUARG7GZ"},"principal":"admin","ticket":"60cdc7e2-70f8-48d3-9f7d-8c98f7040955","roles":"[]"}
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Inflater has been closed
```

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I had it commented, but nothing happens when I introduce it back (see edit)

Comment: Just to be sure, when you replace `scatter_matrix(...)` by `df.plot()` you obtain a figure? If this is the case, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest when I do that it also hangs.

Comment: It's then the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240656/how-to-plot-using-matplotlib-and-pandas-in-pyspark-environment). Not sure how useful the answer is.